# DIV float left without set height

Tags: html

working on a new site and having issues floating DIVs left with the overflow wrapping to the next line.

Sample: http://gohmm.matthewgideon.com/get-involved/sponsorships/

you'll notice when you reduce the size of the browser - the 1st set of images at the bottom are correct, but they should wrap to the next line after they reach 100% across the screen.

If I add a height to the Divs it works, but I did not want to set a height. Here is the basic coding I'm using.

```
#sponsorshipWrapper { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 100%;}

#sponsorship {
display: block;
float: left;
padding: 0 20px 40px;
width: calc(20% - 40px);
}
```

Ultimately I'm trying to pull a query of posts and place the in a grid pattern, left to right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the #sponsorship id (which really should be a class, since it's used multiple times) a height. For example:

```
#sponsorship {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height:300px;
}
```

This should probably be done in all media queries.

Comment: I was avoiding setting a height, but for now will just go with that as an option.